# Logistic Regression prediction faults

Tags: machine-learning, classification, logistic-regression, prediction

I have been trying to solve this problem of titanic survived problem. Where i splitted x to be the passengers and y to be the survived. But the problem is i couldn't able to get the y_pred (ie) prediction results. As it is 0 for all the values. I get 0 value as prediction. It would be helpful for me if anyone can solve it. As it is my first classifier problem as a beginner

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Umer/train.csv')
x = df['PassengerId'].values.reshape(-1,1)
y = df['Survived']


from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(x,y,test_size = 0.25, 
random_state = 0)


from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc_x = StandardScaler()
x_train = sc_x.fit_transform(x_train)
x_test = sc_x.transform(x_test)

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
classifier = LogisticRegression()
classifier.fit(x_train,y_train)

#predicting the test set results


y_pred = classifier.predict(x_test)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't reproduce the same result, in fact, I copied-pasted your code and did not get them all zeros as you described the issue as, instead I got:

```
[0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

Nevertheless, there are a few things I noticed in your approach that you may want to know about:

1. The default separator in [`Pandas read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) is `,` , so if your dataset variables separated by a `tab` (*same like the one I have*) , you then should specify the separator like this:

   ```
   df = pd.read_csv('titanic.csv', sep='\t')
   ```
2. `PassengerId` has no useful information that your model may learn from in order to predict the `Survived` people, it's just a continuous number that increments with each new passenger. Generally speaking, in classification, you need to avail of all features that make your model learns from (*unless of course there are redundant features that add no information to the model*) especially in your dataset, it's a multivariate dataset.
3. There is no point of scaling the `PassengerId`, because [features scaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_scaling) is usually used when features highly vary in magnitudes, units and range (*e.g. 5kg and 5000gms*) and in your case, as I mentioned, it's just an incremental integer which has no *real* information to the model.
4. One last thing, you should get your data as type `float` for `StandardScaler` to avoid warnings like the follow:

   ```
   DataConversionWarning: Data with input dtype int64 was converted to float64 by StandardScaler.
   ```

   So you do convert like this from the beginning:

   ```
   x = df['PassengerId'].values.astype(float).reshape(-1,1)
   ```

*Finally if you're still getting the same result, then please add a link to your dataset.*

---

### Update

After providing the dataset, it turns out that the result you're getting is correct, that's again because of reason number `2` I mentioned above (that is `PassengerId` provides no useful information to the model so it cannot predict correctly!)

You can test it yourself via comparing the [log loss](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.log_loss.html) before and after adding more features from the dataset:

```
from sklearn.metrics import log_loss
df = pd.read_csv('train.csv', sep=',')
x = df['PassengerId'].values.reshape(-1,1)
y = df['Survived']
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(x,y,test_size = 0.25,
random_state = 0)
classifier = LogisticRegression()
classifier.fit(x_train,y_train)
y_pred_train = classifier.predict(x_train)
# calculate and print the loss function using only the PassengerId
print(log_loss(y_train, y_pred_train))
#predicting the test set results
y_pred = classifier.predict(x_test)
print(y_pred)
```

**Output**

```
13.33982681120802
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0]
```

Now by using many "*supposedly-useful*" information:

```
from sklearn.metrics import log_loss
df = pd.read_csv('train.csv', sep=',')
# denote the words female and male as 0 and 1
df['Sex'].replace(['female','male'], [0,1], inplace=True)
# try three features that you think they are informative to the model
# so it can learn from them
x = df[['Fare', 'Pclass', 'Sex']].values.reshape(-1,3)
y = df['Survived']
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(x,y,test_size = 0.25,
random_state = 0)
classifier = LogisticRegression()
classifier.fit(x_train,y_train)
y_pred_train = classifier.predict(x_train)
# calculate and print the loss function with the above 3 features
print(log_loss(y_train, y_pred_train))
#predicting the test set results
y_pred = classifier.predict(x_test)
print(y_pred)
```

**Output**

```
7.238735137632405
[0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0
 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0
 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1
 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1
 1]
```

---

In Conclusion:

As you can see, the loss gave better value (lesser than before) and the prediction is now more reasonable!

Comment: hey thanks for answering. I still got the same zeros as my prediction.. so here's a dataset link so that you can share your results https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/data

Comment: @UmerSalman I updated my answer, please accept it if it helped you.

Comment: @Yahya This is really helpful info for a beginner. :) Thank you.